# Using smartphone train ticket in Italy

Tags: trains, tickets, italy, cellphones

Is it legal to use electronic tickets from a third party app (e.g. "[trainline](https://trainline.de)") in a train operated by [Trenitalia](https://www.trenitalia.com/)? I don't want to print the tickets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the type of ticket you have bought. From the [Trainline's Terms and conditions](https://www.thetrainline.com/terms)

> **Print-Your-Own tickets**
>
> Print-Your-Own tickets must be printed clearly on A4 paper and taken
>   with you when you travel. If these tickets aren’t printed, they’re not
>   valid and you won’t be able to use the excuse that your printer’s ink
>   ran dry or your dog ate them.
>
> If your Print-Your-Own tickets have your name on them, you must carry
>   an ID matching the same name, otherwise your tickets won’t be valid.
>   Some operators apply restrictions to Print-Your-Own tickets and you
>   must read these during our booking process.
>
> **Mobile Tickets**
>
> Mobile Tickets aren’t available on all devices or routes, so before
>   you book make sure your device is compatible. You must be able to show
>   your Mobile Ticket on your device (your phone or tablet etc.), so it
>   can be clearly read and you may need to activate your Mobile Ticket
>   before boarding the train, coach or bus to make it valid. If Mobile
>   Tickets have been booked for more than one passenger, then all
>   passengers must travel together.
>
> **etickets**
>
> etickets are emailed as a PDF attachment to you, meaning you’ll need a
>   mobile device that can open PDFs and has internet access to receive
>   the email. You can use them in one of the following ways –
>
> - Open the PDF attachment and show the ticket on your mobile device.
> - Print the eticket.
> - Download the eticket on our app.
> - Download and show the eticket in your Apple Wallet if you are using an Apple Wallet enabled Apple device – there’ll be a live link in the email we send you.
>
> An eticket can only be used by one customer for one valid journey and
>   it’s a criminal offence to amend and/or reproduce an eticket for
>   fraudulent use. If two passengers show the same eticket for travel,
>   they’ll could both be treated as invalid. You’re responsible for any
>   fraudulent use of your eticket.
>
> **Smartcard**
>
> For some bookings you can have your ticket delivered to your
>   Smartcard. If you’re using an existing Smartcard, you must make sure
>   you enter the correct reference number as we can’t change this once
>   payment’s been taken. You must carry your Smartcard with you when you
>   travel and make sure you validate it at the start and end of your
>   journey by using the ticket barriers.
>
> For more information on the ticket types, we recommend you read the
>   terms and conditions for the operator you’ll be travelling with.